# Ajax request failed 500 internal server error

Tags: angularjs, ajax, http, spring-mvc, http-status-code-500

I have got an 500 Internal server error angualar ajax request.
In java spring is configured.

Java:

```
'@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="setData")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelClass setData(@RequestBody String value) {
        System.out.println("********** "+ value);
        ModelClass paramEntity = new ModelClass();
        paramEntity.setText(value);
        return paramEntity;
    }'
```

JS:`$scope.setData=function(){
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:'setData',
            data:$scope.textValue
        }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
            console.log("Exception");
        });
    }`

Comment: Exception Log: Jan 01, 2019 2:13:04 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver logException
WARNING: Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class org.constr.controller.ModelClass]

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@ResponseBody` and returning a `ModelClass` object. What you need here is a [`MessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/messaging/converter/MessageConverter.html). For example, you can use [MappingJackson2MessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/messaging/converter/MappingJackson2MessageConverter.html), the `Jackson 2` based implementaton of `MessageConverter`:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="objectMapper" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
    ...
</bean>
```

***NOTE:***

Also use the `produces` element of `@RequestMapping` annotation in controller to mention the producible media types of the mapped request. For example, if you want to send a `JSON` response:

```
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, ...)
```

***Further Reading:***

[`1.10.7. Message Converters`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-message-converters) from Spring Framework Documentation 5.1.3.RELEASE